# how does stackoverflow put the question string as filename?

Tags: .net, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does stackoverflow add the question title to the end of it's routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055415/how-does-stackoverflow-add-the-question-title-to-the-end-of-its-routes)

Hello all,

I'm inteding to develop a website somewhat similar to stackoverflow. I would also like that the question asked in my website will serve as the filename of the page.
For example, stackoverflow question like "***How does stackoverflow add the question title to the end of it's routes?***" will result in this filename (as taken from the address bar): "[Adding ID and title to URL slugs in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055415/)***how-does-stackoverflow-add-the-question-title-to-the-end-of-its-routes***"

How it is done in .NET technology?

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the technology you want to use.

In ASP.NET MVC world, you can use the built in Routing such as:

Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Question", // Route name
    "questions/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Questions", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = "0", 
        name = UrlParameter.Optional 
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string name)
{
    var model = _db.Questions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    return View(model);
}
```

Prior to .NET 3.5 Sp1, you could use [Url Rewriting](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

As Scott says, there was 2 main modules for this [UrlRewriter.net](http://UrlRewriter.net) and [UrlRewriting.net](http://UrlRewriting.net)

Though they were mainly use in ASP.NET 2.0, they work great in 3.5 as well.

Comment: This really doesn't help.   (He's asking for the routing framework itself)

Comment: edited ... I didn't read the question like that :) my bad.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I will check it out in the coming days.

Comment: don't write `Thank you`, if you want to say Thank you, upvote the answer, and make it correct answer if answer was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ASP.Net MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416514.aspx) with [ASP.Net Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Comment: ...and its really just there for readability.  if you edit the "name" part of a SO URL, it still takes you to the same page.  only the id number actually matters

Comment: Thank you all guys. I will check it out in the coming days.

Answer (score 0):

All of the other answers (MVC, ASP.NET Routing) but this can be done with ANY technology using URL rewriting. URL rewriting is supported by all web servers. Check out http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html for some apache how-to's

Edit: http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/030522.htm how to do url rewriting in .NET using httpmodules

Comment: However, he's asking about .Net.

Comment: yes I know. URL rewriting can be done in .NET as well as any other tech. Added link to do it with HttpModules.

Comment: Thank you all guys. I will check it out in the coming days.

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow uses ASP.NET MVC routes to accomplish this. The route would be something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Questions route",                                      // Route name
    "questions/{id}/{title}",                               // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Questions", action = "Question", id = "", title = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

Actually, what really matters to StackOverflow is the {id} part, since that is what is used to retrieve the question. The title is only used for Search Engine Optimization. You can try it yourself, just note that those three URLs give the same result:

[how does stackoverflow put the question string as filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064010/how-does-stackoverflow-put-the-question-string-as-filename)

[how does stackoverflow put the question string as filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064010/i-can-write-anything-here)

[how does stackoverflow put the question string as filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064010/)

Comment: Thank you all guys. I will check it out in the coming days.