# Custome MVC Url Rout to display mixture of Id and UrlSlug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi ' I'm gonna to apply the mixture of Id and slug as a url in my blog url like this

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286556/using-httpclient-to-log-in-to-hpps-server
```

to do this I have defined this Url in my global.asax

```
  routes.MapRoute("IdSlugRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
                            new {controller = "Blog", action = "Post", id = UrlParameter.Optional,slug=""});
```

but when I run my application Url is look like this :

```
http://localhost:1245/Blog/Post?postId=dd1140ce-ae5e-4003-8090-8d9fbe253e85&slug=finally-i-could-do-solve-it
```

I don't want to have those ? and = in Url ! I just wanna to separate them by slash 
how can I do about this please ??

bu the way the actionresult that returns this Url is this :

```
 public ActionResult Post(Guid postId,string slug)
        {
            var post = _blogRepository.GetPostById(postId);
            return View("Post",post);
        }
```

Comment: How are you calling this route? can you provide an example of your ActionLink etc?

Comment: I just Edited and added the actionreslust that calls the route

Comment: Do you call this from an ActionLink like so... `@Html.ActionLink("foo", "Post", new { controller = "Blog", postId = 1, slug = "foo-bar" })`

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Post", "Blog", new { postId = item.Id, slug = item.UrlSlug }, null)
        </div>
        <div>}

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Comment: "id" needs to be "postId" in the route definition, and the definition must appear before default route definition(if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting both your postId and slug to be `UrlParameter.Optional`?
`routes.MapRoute("IdSlugRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{postId}/{slug}",
                            new {controller = "Blog", action = "Post", postId = UrlParameter.Optional,slug=UrlParameter.Optional});`

**EDIT**

I got this to work locally. What I've got is a model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public Guid PostID { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

A Controller with two actions:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

        var model = new HomeViewModel { PostID = guid, Slug = "this-is-a-test" };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Post(Guid postID, string slug)
    {
        // get the post based on postID
    }
}
```

And a View with an actionlink:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.HomeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@Html.ActionLink("Click me!", "Post", new { postId = Model.PostID, slug = Model.Slug})
```

To get the routing to work I had to hard-code the route as it comes before the Default route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("IdSlugRoute", "Home/Post/{postID}/{slug}",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Post", postID = Guid.Empty, slug = UrlParameter.Optional });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

Comment: yeah I just test it , I got the same hideous Url!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your custom route is ABOVE the default one. It will stop at the first matching route it finds.

Answer (score 0):

change your route to use postId rather than Id

```
routes.MapRoute("IdSlugRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{postId}/{slug}",
                            new {controller = "Blog", action = "Post", postId = UrlParameter.Optional,slug=""});
```