# How to bind model during an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a dynamic url processor

```
public ActionResult DynamicUrl(string slug = null)
```

this method works through the slug (btw, what does slug stand for?) and works out if the slug is displaying a product or performing a product search.

As part of the product search, I have a page=1 querystring param.

```
E.g. /Womens/Dresses?page=2
```

Usually I would do this in a normal product search action which binds the page querystring to the ProductSearch model.

```
public ActionResult Results(ProductSearchModel  searchModel)
```

How can I bind the querstring during the action? For example

```
public ActionResult DynamicUrl(string slug = null)
{
    ProductSearchModel psm = new ProductSearchModel();

    //Auto bind psm here.
    // E.g. Controller.BindModel(psm);
}
```

Hope I am not way off course on this.

Comment: A slug is a human readable, friendly part of a url usually appended to the end of the url. If you enter just `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386176` in  the address bar, notice how it appends `/how-to-bind-model-during-an-action` to the end of it when the page is rendered

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055415/adding-id-and-title-to-url-slugs-in-asp-net-mvc

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If you have a query string `?page=2`, then the method should have a matching parameter - public ActionResult DynamicUrl(string slug, int page)` (no need to have `string slug = null` since `string` is a reference type)

Comment: **None of the comments above are on the same subject I am asking about.**

Comment: Why you dont want to use Request.QueryString ?

Comment: My first comment was a response to your query _"btw, what does slug mean?"_ and my second comment shows how to add a parameter so you can use `Model.Page = page` instead of _"resorting to Model.Page = Request.Querystring["Page"]"_. What is it that you really need to know?

Comment: I meant, what does "slug" stand for. Is it an acronym for something? As for the second comment, i want to bind the models to any querystring. So i do not want to have to list them all as params in the action, then assign them manually to the model. I have updated my last code example and hope that clears up that confusion.

Comment: @Valamas-AUS - Slug isn't an acronym, it's just a name adopted by web devs to parts of Urls. I'd generally classify them as configurable URL parts so the slug would be the part the user can control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
UpdateModel(psm);
```

This will bind the current form collection to the model specified.

You can also use:

```
TryUpdateModel(psm);
```

This version won't throw an exception if something fails and returns `true` or `false`.