# Stack Overflow, urls how do they work??, do they redirect?

Tags: php, slug, friendly-url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stack Overflow Question Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677158/stack-overflow-question-routing)

before you jump out... i know questions about stackoverflow urls have been asked 1231234123123123 times. i know because i read all of them.

this question is different, i know how they work, almost

there are one thing that i dont know EXACTLY what they did.

1. when i change the "pretty" `this-is-a-nice-question` to `bla-bla` it changes back to the original question name.

how did they do that do they change this part to the original? is it redirect? one thing im sure of is that they dont do that on the client side.

Comment: You could find out if it's a redirect by using something like `wget` or `curl` to see the actual responses that come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a redirect.

```
> wget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459811/stack-overflow-urls-how-do-they
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /questions/7459811/stack-overflow-urls-how-do-they-work-do-they-redirect [following]
```

Comment: yeah thats what i thought, thanks.