# Changing route in MVC not including layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing strange problem in my MVC application.

I had navigation link of page like this-

```
<a href="/Home/CardDetails?cardID=@Model.cardID">@Model.cardTitle</a>
```

So i changed its route to make it canonical and added an entry in `route.config` file above "Default" route-

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HomeCardDetails",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{cardID}/{cardTitle}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CardDetails", cardTitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then modified link according to route as-

```
<a href="/Home/cardDetails/@Model.cardID/@Model.cardTitle">@Model.cardTitle</a>
```

**Controller method-**

```
   public ActionResult CardDetails(CardModel card) {
            var cardDetail = (from u in db.CardTables
                              where u.IsApproved == "YES" && u.CardID == card.cardID
                              join v in db.FunRegistereds
                              on u.FKCardID equals v.UserID
                              select new CardModel {
                                  cardID = u.CardID,
                                  cardHashCode = u.CardHashCode,
                                  cardDate = u.CardDate,
                                  cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                                  cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                                  cardTitle = u.CardTitle.Replace(" ","-"),
                                  fkcardID = Convert.ToInt32(u.FKCardID),
                                  aboutCard = u.AboutCard,
                                  uploadedBy = u.UploadedBy == null ? "Anonymous" : u.UploadedBy,
                                  cardspamcount = u.CardSpams == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(u.CardSpams),
                                  cardfavoritecount = u.CardFavorites == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(u.CardFavorites),
                                  cardlovecount = u.CardLoves == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(u.CardLoves),
                                  cardhatecount = u.CardHates == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(u.CardHates)
                              }).SingleOrDefault();

            if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Session["LoggedInUser"] != null) {
                if (cardDetail.fkcardID == this.LoggedInUser.UserID) {
                    ViewBag.Username = cardDetail.uploadedBy;
                }
                return View(cardDetail);
            }
            else {
                return View(cardDetail);
            }

        }
```

Now this new route seems to work fine. But View never comes with layout now.

It renders page without layout.

My actionResult is type `View` and it adds entry of `viewstart.cshtml` while rendering it.
I just want to know why this is happening and what happened in between?

Comment: @Exception, This is not my problem, I need to show url with title- like `somedomain.com/378/My-new-title` . So It has to come with title.

Comment: just include @{ Layout=" Path " } explicitely in view...

Comment: @user3163213....worked,,?????

Comment: @Exception, Here i have edited question for you.

Comment: everything works fine just layout is not coming ...????

Comment: @Exception, Yes exactly!

Comment: there is problem in this return View(cardDetail); it should be like return View("cardDetail");

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be declared on top of the View "CardDetails" which has a model of type "CardModel".

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Show you full routes and a beginning of your View file.
Why do you use {cardTitle} in the route ?
Does it work with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "HomeCardDetails",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{cardID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "CardDetails", cardID= UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I need to show url with title- like somedomain.com/378/My-new-title . So It has to come with title.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174820/how-to-add-page-title-in-url-in-asp-net-mvc-url-generation and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677158/stack-overflow-question-routing . Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055415/adding-id-and-title-to-url-slugs-in-asp-net-mvc